# Sending data in through multiple screens

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns

In my app , at a particular screen there is Arraylist which is a source of recycler view . There are many buttons on that screen which takes you to next screen , next screen may be a single plain activity or activity with view pager and tablayout and that fragment may contain buttons which takes you to next screen .In some screen i can edit the Song class field too . My problem is that i am confused whether the send the list to next screen and further next fragment or next screens through intent or should i make that static and access it anywhere . Again and again i have to parcel wrap and then unwrap then send it to fragment then wrap for the fragment then unwarp it then send it to adpater attached to fragment , this is long process and  i am afraid that anyone can change that list in any screen and secondly this whole process is cumbersome every time sending intent and receiving intent .

Comment: Ok, You should use preference. when you send or update any think do it, at last, you will save in preference and use it.

Comment: share your code .

Comment: @Jackey Kabra you wan to store that code in shared pref and fetch it everytime?

Comment: the entire class is big which , part of code you specifically want

Comment: i have read using static is bad practice , which may lead to memory leaks so should static lists be used ?

Comment: You will make one public method and fetch it .

Answer (score 0):

Passing the Values from Intent have chances of data loss so do not pass the multiple Values with the Intent. So it will be better to access the values from a Static class if the values are not changing. If sometimes values are changing then pass these with Intent. 
You can also go with the SharedPreferences, it will be more feasible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift to flux architecture. Redux store kind of state management. 
Who ever needs data queries to store. And data changes automatically dispatched to listeners.

Comment: is this more relevant in react type language, will it fit in normal andorid architecture

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are NOT made to pass data between Activities/Fragments. They are here to store data that need to persist when the app is closed.

An option could be to use some kind of "cache" class that will store your data. So let's say you display the list of whatever data you want on the first screen, then the user selects one of the items to see the details/modify it. So you give the position of this data (in the array stored in the cache) to your next fragment and this next fragment asks the cache to give to it the data, based on the position it has received.

### Example

**Cache class**

```
public class Cache{
    List<Object> data;

    // ... Implementation

    public List<Object> getData(){
       return this.data;
    }
    public setData(List<Object> data){
       this.data = data;
    }   

    public Object getObject(int position){
       return data.get(position);
    }
}
```

**List Activity**

```
public class ListDataActivity extends ListActivity{

    public void onCreate(...){
        // get the data
        ...
        // Set the data to the cache
        Cache.getInstance().setData(data);
        // Display the list
        ...
    }

    public void onItemClicked(...){
        Intent intent =....
        intent.put(ITEM_POSITION, pos);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Details Activity**

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(...){
        //...
        // get data from the cache
        int pos  = getIntent.getInt(ITEM_POSITION);
        Object obj = Cache.getInstance().getObject(pos);
        // Display the details
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the harm in using static lists?

Comment: There are different implementations possible. But generally I prefer to use a separated class/object to manage data shared between components. But it can be a Singleton or a class using static variables. Personally I prefer the first approach especially because I'm currently using Dagger 2 where you can define scopes, so it generates singletons like which remain only for a defined part of your app. But what I said is to NOT use SharedPreferences as a temporary cache, I haven't mentioned statics.